# Azure devops (VSTS) and GITHUB: Current status on largest allowed repository size

Tags: github, azure-devops, gvfs

We would like to give [VFSforGIT](https://github.com/Microsoft/VFSForGit) (formerly known as GVFS) a try, but currently this only works with VSTS and GitHUB. So we can't run a local VFSforGIT server, since no open source server implementation exists yet.

However, we expect our repository to become hundreds of gigabytes large, since we store assets for 3D movie production. Not a lot of assets, just large ones.

What is current status on the maximum allowed repository size (with a paid plan)?

According to the [Azure devops documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/limits?view=vsts), there currently is no hard limit, only a recommendation:

> In uncommon circumstances, repositories may be larger than 10GB. For instance, the Windows repository is at least 300GB. For that reason, we do not have a hard block in place. If your repository grows beyond 10GB, consider using Git-LFS, GVFS, or Azure Artifacts to refactor your development artifacts.

What is meant with *refactor your development artifacts*? How would using GVFS make a repository smaller (if that is meant with *refactor*)? Maybe it can use another server for storing large files?

Another problem is the push size limit, this is currently 5GB, which might be too small for say video files or some Substance Painter files, but for most cases, this will work.

Answer (score 1):

GVFS, *currently being renamed to VFS*, is a system through which only it interacts (downloads) with the files that are opened, keeping the other files unused as empty (in local) and maintained in the repository.

[image]
<sub>(source: [vfsforgit.org](https://vfsforgit.org/images/how-does-vfsforgit-work.png))</sub>

Regarding ***refactoring*** refers to the **action of re-indexing the repository files** but with programs (LFS, etc) that *reduce the size to be uploaded to the repository*.

Regarding the use, it is recommended that you take into account that:

- Windows10 must be installed
- There are Git commands that GVFS does not support
- It has to be used with GitBash (GVFS)

Finally, the repository has no limit (currently I have it in 1TB) for now

Comment: Thanks for the info. So VFSforGit is compatible with LFS? Do you know if it is possible to use an external server for the LFS files? GitHub supports this, but I don't know if that works together with VFSforGit.

Comment: @Ziriax LFS is a tool that replaces large files with text pointers inside Git, while it stores the contents of the file on a remote server such as GitHub.com or GitHub Enterprise. The use of LFS is possible only that it would be a bit contradictory in VFSforGit that already in case it allows the upload of gramdes files.